# How to control bootstrap wizard modal final button

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am using a [wizard modal](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Wizard-Modal-Bootstrap-jQuery.html) for my step-by-step form. I would like to control the generation of the last button, which currently generates a button labeled "Complete" on the final step. I want to hide that "Complete" button since I am including a submit button on the last step. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following **CSS** to hide the complete button:

```css
.modal-content [data-step="complete"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/aystarz52/pen/mZaGbz?editors=1000